# Colours on webpage changing in shade depending on location

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working on a website, and I have noticed something when working with the web page. Two elements have the same class, but the shade of the colors is different. Does anyone know what could cause something like that?

**EDIT**
here is some of the code:

The Class:

```
.summer{
background-color: #0077be;
/*background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0077be  0%, #fff 100%);

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0077be  0%, #fff 100%);

background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0077be  0%, #fff 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0077be ), color-stop(100, #fff));

background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0077be  0%, #fff 100%);

background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0077be  0%, #fff 100%);*/
}
```

The HTML:

```
<button onclick="prnt();">Print</button>
<div class="recipe" id="0">
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <p>The recipes you'll find here are ones you can use to impress guests at your next get together</p>
    </div>
</div> <!--recipe card end-->
<div class="recipe" id="1">
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab">Chicken Clubhouse Sandwiches</a>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Chicken Clubhouse Sandwiches</h1>
        <div class="head">
            <b>From: </b> <a href="#">Source</a><br>
            <b>Makes: </b> 2 Sandwiches<br>
            <button onclick="makeLink(1);">Share Link</button><br>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="pic">
                <img src="/uploads/1/0/4/0/104012940/custom_themes/406340590114946394/files/images/lunch2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ing">
                <b>Ingredients</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>6 slices of bread</li>
                    <li>6 Slices of bacon</li>
                    <li>Cooked chicken breast, cut into chunks</li>
                    <li>Shredded Lettuce</li>
                    <li>Sliced Tomato</li>
                    <li>Mayonnaise</li>
                    <li>Heinz Chili Sauce</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <b>How to Make</b>
                <ol>
                    <li>Toast the bread and cook the bacon</li>
                    <li>Assemble in the following order:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Toast</li>
                            <li>Mayo</li>
                            <li>Lettuce</li>
                            <li>Tomato</li>
                            <li>Toast</li>
                            <li>Chicken</li>
                            <li>Bacon</li>
                            <li>Chili Sauce</li>
                            <li>Toast</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--recipe card end-->
```

The Assigning of the Class:

```
function button(season){
switch(season){
  case 1:
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
        button.className+="spring";
    });
        break;
  case 2:
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
        button.className += "summer";
    });
        break;
  case 3:
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
        button.className+="fall";
    });
        break;
  case 4:
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
        button.className+="winter";
    });
        break;
  default:
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')).map(function(button) {
               button.style.backgroundColor="#FFF";
    });
        break;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Post up some code. What is the CSS class definition, what does the HTML look like?

Comment: Either one of the elements has another `class` , a unique `id` or `attribute` or `tag`, and those have `css styles` on them which overwrite the `class styles`. Eg `<p class="red">This text is red.</p>` and `<p class="red blue">This text is blue.</p>`

Comment: I used to have this same issue on a laptop I had once... after plenty of CSS tests, I came to the conclusion it had something to do with the screen itself. Not sure if the same is happening here but it sounds a lot like it.

Comment: It does sound like a monitor issue to me. Perhaps you could reduce your code to a small test example where you just assign the CSS class to a few divs and place them around the page to test.

Comment: Yeah, I moved the locations of one of the buttons and that seems to be the issue. Guess I'll have to put the other button near the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Check for these possibilities:

-ID of the element

-Classes of the element

-style attribute is added to the element in HTML

Comment: I am not sure if it's any of that. I tried directly assigning the color to the element and it still does that. Thanks for the suggesting though

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```css
.container {
    width: 300px; 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.container:nth-of-type(3) {
    border-color: red;
}
.container:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Content</div>
<div class="container">Content</div>
<div class="container">Content</div>
```

otherwise you can do with div id's

```css
.container {
    width: 300px; 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
#divtwo.container {
    border-color: red;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#006678;
}
#divthree.container {
    border-color: blue;
    background-color:#009966;
}
```

```html
<div id="divone" class="container">Content</div>
<div id="divtwo" class="container">Content</div>
<div id="divthree" class="container">Content</div>
```